# Flatpickr Validate That startDate is before endDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I have two DateTime inputs using flatpickr. It seems like the normal custom validation won't work on the input.

This is what I've tried. However the form can still submit and change the first date to be after the second

```
 // Validate that the start date is not after the end date
    var validateDates = function(startDate, endDate, endDateInput) {
        // Detect if the start and end date are valid (startDate is not after endDate) for create/edit modals
        // If end date is invalid, leave the displayed duration at 0
        getDifferenceInDays(startDate, endDate);

        if (startDate > endDate) {
            $('input[type="text"].eval-close-window-input')[1].setCustomValidity('End date must not be before start date.');
            $('input[type="text"].eval-close-window-input')[1].reportValidity();
            return false;

            // endDateInput.reportValidity()
        } else {
            $('input[type="text"].eval-close-window-input')[1];

            return true;
        }

    };
```

The input I am targeting is the second out of these two.

```
// The input that I originally created
<input type="hidden" id="open-window-747" name="open-window" class="ml-1 pl-2 form-check-inline small-selector flatpickr-input form-control input eval-open-window-input" value="2019-11-23 3:36">

// Targeting this input
<input class="form-control flatpickr-input input active eval-close-window-input flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: might it be comparing those values as string instead of date? we cant tell what getDifferenceInDays is here?

Comment: the difference in dates isnt doing the comparing. I did console.log to test if the ```if (startDate > endDate)``` is being trigged and it is

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry but I believe I had to select the correct one with JavaScript.